# VSTS build/release from multiple sources to Azure virtual directories

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My team has an Azure App Services Web App where we house three major components:

1. Our main Node.js server and API, which is at the root
2. A secondary API, which is in a virtual directory
3. Our front-end web app (also served from a Node.js server), which is in another virtual directory

Each of those three components is maintained in its own git repo in VSTS. Additionally, the Web App has three slots: `dev`, `ppe`, and `prod`.

We are trying to move our build processes out of Azure and into VSTS. What we'd like to be able to do is the following:

- When there's a new commit to `master` in any of the three repos, create a dev build and deploy it directly to the appropriate virtual directory in the `dev` slot.
- When a component is ready to be released - whether that means a new commit in a special `RELEASE` branch or manually triggering a release process - create a production build, deploy it to `ppe` and, on user approval, swap the `ppe` and `prod` slots.

The complication here is that, when any component is deployed to `ppe`, we also need to deploy the latest released versions of *all three* components to `ppe`, since Azure does not have the ability to swap virtual directories independently.

What I currently have is the following:

- A build process for each of the three repositories, which is triggered on commits to `master` or `RELEASE`. It creates both a development build and a production build and publishes them.
- A dev release process that is triggered on any new builds of `master` in any of the three repositories. It takes the latest dev build from `master` from all three repos and deploys them to their appropriate virtual directories in `dev`.
- A production release process that is triggered on any new build of `RELEASE` in any of the three repositories. It takes the latest production build from `RELEASE` from all three repos, deploys them to the appropriate virtual directories in `ppe` and, on user approval, swaps `ppe` and `prod`.

This works, but it seems pretty clunky, has a lot of wasted work, and it doesn't feel like we're exactly taking advantage of the power of the VSTS build/release pipeline. Is there a better or more accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There is Filters based on the artifacts feature in [environment triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers#env-triggers) of release, so you can base on the build tag(s) to trigger corresponding environments.

Regarding build, you can set the build tag(s) per to current branch by calling [logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) through PowerShell task (`##vso[build.addbuildtag]build tag`)

Regarding ppe scenario, I recommend that you can create a new CI build definition just for ppe related branch and build all components (get others source code by calling git clone command through Command Line task or other tasks (e.g. PowerShell)), then publish results of them, after that deploy them to corresponding slots and Virtual directory in release.